# Trouble with installing Nodemon on Windows machine

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I have been running into some issues while trying to install nodemon globally.
here's what it looks like:

```
$ npm i -g nodemon  
npm ERR! code ENOENT  
npm ERR! syscall lstat  
npm ERR! path C:\Users\krishnna sarrdah\AppData\Roaming\npm  
npm ERR! errno -4058  
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\krishnna sarrdah\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. 
npm ERR! enoent                                                               
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\krishnna sarrdah\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-22T16_04_35_377Z-debug.log
```

Comment: remove -g just use 'npm i nodemon'

Comment: that installs it somehow...but after that, if I type nodemon -v, it says command not recognized

Comment: don't forfet to add a nodemon script in your scripts after that you can start the server by typing just 'nodemon' in your console

Comment: I have installed it in the main file which contains the index.js file the problem still persists

Comment: did you add nodemon script in you package.json

Comment: open your package.json file then under scripts add this code [ "dev": "nodemon app.js"]

Comment: sorry but i paste the code like my file so if your server file is called app use the code that i sent but if it called index.js use this one ["dev":"nodemon index.js"]

Comment: I pasted it in the main JSON file(assuming that's the one), that didn't work :/ .

Comment: what is the error

Comment: command not found.

Comment: i pasted "["dev":"nodemon index.js"] " in the scripts of my main json file

Comment: ok use this code in your console and try again [npm install nodemon --save-dev]

Comment: so I just completely uninstalled node from my system and re-installed it, and tried installing nodemon again, and it worked this time.

Answer (score 0):

Your node installation is slightly out of date, I solved this problem with this

repair Node installation

npm update -g